# Fourier transform harmonic oscillator eigenstates

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics

The normalized eigenfunctions of the quantum harmonic oscillator are
$$\psi_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x),$$
where $n \in \mathbb N_0$ and $H_n$ is the $n$-th Hermite polynomial, see also [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#One-dimensional_harmonic_oscillator)

I am curious if there exists a closed-form expression of the Fourier transform
$$F_{n,m}(k):=\int_{\mathbb R} \psi_n(x)\psi_m(x) e^{-ikx} \ dx$$
for any possible pair $n$, $m$.

Comment: this is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4203025/87355